# Toggling Images with a boolean state of a react functional component

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have a react function component, that I do not want to convert to a class component. I want it to have the functionality so that when it is pressed, the image is changed. However, currently, it is only showing one of the images (checked.png). What am I doing wrong?

```
const SignUpScreen = () => {
  const [check, setCheck] = useState(false);

  const changeImage = () => {
    setCheck((prevCheck) => !prevCheck);
  };

  return (      
       <View>
        <Text>
          Select the box to change the image
        </Text>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => changeImage()}>
          <Image
            source={
              { check } === true
                ? require("../img/unchecked.png")
                : require("../img/checked.png")
            }
          />
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
   );
};

export default SignUpScreen;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove {} around the check

```
const SignUpScreen = () => {
  const [check, setCheck] = useState(false);

  const changeImage = () => {
    setCheck((prevCheck) => !prevCheck);
  };

  return (      
       <View>
        <Text>
          Select the box to change the image
        </Text>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => changeImage()}>
          <Image
            source={
              check === true
                ? require("../img/unchecked.png")
                : require("../img/checked.png")
            }
          />
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
   );
};

export default SignUpScreen;
```

Otherwise it is an object created everytime

Comment: Fantastic! Thank you for this!